# Patch not applied after it gets merged

Tags: git, merge, patch, revision-history

Using the `git flow` tool, I created a feature branch (branched off `dev`), made a bunch of changes, and merged the branch back onto `dev`.

There is a file which I have modified in the feature branch. I can confirm that the revision (let's call it `REV-A`) that modifies the file (`FILE-A`) is present and applied in the feature branch.

However, after the merge, `FILE-A` is in its original (pre-merge) state on the `dev` branch. I can see `REV-A` when I do `git log` on `dev`, and if I follow the lines produced by `git log --graph`, I can trace this commit forward to the merge commit where I merged my feature branch with `dev`.

However, when I do a `git blame` of `FILE-A`, the commit is not there, and the line in question is in its original (pre `REV-A` commit).

Additionally, `git show REV-A | patch -p1` results in the patch being applied cleanly. After that, `git diff` looks the same as `git show REV-A`.

What's going on? How is it that a merge introduces a revision into the branch history, but doesn't actually apply it? Are there any other changes from that merge which aren't being applied???

Comment: Was the feature branch rebased at any point?

Comment: Please post the results of `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --full-history --ancestry-path ^REV_A HEAD` (with the perplexing merge checked out).

Comment: It would be very helpful to see what commands you ran. Even better if you have a shell add-on that shows the branch in which you ran the commands. My guess is that you might have merged `dev` into your feature branch rather than merging your feature branch into `dev`. But, that's just wild speculation without seeing what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 2):

If some change hunks appear to be missing from a merge result, the first and in my experience the only question you need to ask is whether [git diff](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) shows them as changes between the merge base and the branch tip. Ask it:

```
git diff $merge^1...$merge^2 -- FILE-A  # `$merge^2` was `feature` as of the merge
                                         # `$merge^1` was `dev`
```

That three-dot syntax above is specific to diff, everybody at least sometimes wants to see what change hunks merge is seeing for a branch.

If the changes don't appear in the output then those `REV_A` changes were reverted in some commit between `REV_A` and the merge, whether by a previous merge (to either branch), in which case you get to ask the same question again about that merge, or directly, by some equivalent of `git revert`.

If the changes *do* appear in the output then, since patch applies the hunks cleanly, the changes were manually reverted in that merge.

Answer (score 2):

Do you still have the commands you ran? This would be helpful in tracking down where things may have gone awry. I can't help but think that somehow the feature was not 'finished' correctly. Can you confirm you typed `git flow feature finish my_feature`?

I have simulated a feature with the commands below, but have not encountered the issue you describe. If your steps deviate from what I have below it would be great to compare how, and where.

```
MBP:git-test acanby (master)$ echo "Original Code" > file.txt
MBP:git-test acanby (master)$ git commit -am "First commit"
MBP:git-test acanby (master)$ git flow init
MBP:git-test acanby (develop)$ git flow feature start my_feature
MBP:git-test acanby (feature/my_feature)$ echo "New feature here" >> file.txt 
MBP:git-test acanby (feature/my_feature)$ git commit -am "Feature change"
MBP:git-test acanby (feature/my_feature)$ git flow feature finish my_feature
MBP:git-test acanby (develop)$ git blame file.txt 
  ^d96c279 (acanby 2015-02-16 20:36:22 +1100 1) Original Code
  62a38725 (acanby 2015-02-16 20:38:37 +1100 2) New feature here
MBP:git-test acanby (develop)$ git log --oneline
  62a3872 Feature change
  d96c279 First commit
```

Using these commands I was able to complete a feature using the git-flow workflow.

If you're after more info about the git-flow workflow (and specifically the commands and what they do), there is a great cheat sheet available [here](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/).